# param is missing or the value is empty: todo

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Всем привет, пытаюсь сделать submit link вместо кнопки, но не могу понять что делаю не так при нажатии вылезает ошибка:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: todo
```

index.html.rb

```
<h1>Здачи</h1>

<table>


  <% @project_index.each do |project| %>
    <tr>
<h2><%= project.title %></h2>

    <ul>
    <% project.todos.each do |todo| %>
        <li><%= todo.text %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</table>

    <h2>Новая задача</h2>
  <%= form_for :todo, url: todo_create_path do |f| %>

        <p>
            <%= f.text_field :text, placeholder:"Название задачи..."%>
        </p>

        <p>
            <%= f.collection_select(:project_id, Project.all, :id, :title) %>
        </p>

<%= form_tag root_path, id: "form" do %>
<%= link_to "OK", todo_create_path, id: "your_link" %>
<% end %>
<% end %>


</div>
```

todo.controller

```
class TodoController < ApplicationController
  def index
  @todos = Todo.all 
  end

  def create
    @todo = Todo.create(todo_params)

    redirect_to root_path

  end

  def update
  end
  private
  def todo_params
    params.require(:todo).permit(:text, :project_id)
  end


end
```

application.js

```
$(document).on("click", "#your_link", function(){
   $("#form").submit();
});
```

что не так?

Comment: У вас в `application.js` прямо приведено, какую разметку вы должны сделать. Вы сделали только половину того, что от вас требовалось. И судя по этому коду, это учебное задание, о решении которого вы должны догадаться самостоятельно.

Comment: я делал <%= form_for :todo, id: "form", url: todo_create_path do |f| %> , он выдает мне ошибку param is missing or the value is empty: todo, т.е он не передает параметры из формы

Comment: Мысль в верном направлении. Но посмотрите, какая получается разметка. Это точно то, чего вы хотели?

Comment: <%= form_for :todo, id="form", url: todo_create_path do |f| %> ошибка wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2) он говорит что я даю 3 значения а ждет 1 или 2 но я то переда только text и project_id

Comment: тупой я, не могу понять что я не так делаю

Comment: <%= form_tag todo_create_path, id: "form" do %>  убрал все f все равно не работает

Comment: *но я то переда только text и project_id* да ну? (1) `:todo`, (2) `id="form"`, (3) `url: todo_create_path`. Время изучать Ruby?

Comment: да я пытаюсь изучать, но Вы не представляете сколько информации я уже перелопатил что бы понять как это оформить верно

Comment: Представляю. Но важно не количество, а релевантность. Стоило с самого начала глянуть [документацию к `form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for). Впрочем, чтобы ею воспользоваться, знать основы Ruby всё равно необходимо.

Comment: мне дали определенную документацию для изучения, потому что я изначально вообще не знал этого языка, я все изучил, но информации как видите не достаточно, на некоторые задания были просто ссылки вот например как с этой, сделайте submit вместо кнопки и ссылка на то как примерно она должна выглядеть, а как правильно ее оформлять не слова, я даже не знаю что и где мне смотреть, постоянно испытываю нехватку информации. Мое желание быть разработчиком каким бы она не было не достаточно что бы им стать.

Comment: Что означает JS, как я вижу, поняли. Теперь вам нужно добиться предполагаемого там эффекта средствами Rails. Ссылку на документацию нужной вам детали я дал. Ruby, как вы сами утверждаете, "изучили". И у вас есть возможность смотреть, какая разметка получается в браузере. Значит, у вас уже есть всё, что необходимо для решения.

Comment: то что я выполню это задание или нет уже ничего не значит для того кому я это делаю, потому что у меня осталось слишком мало времени, я пытаюсь уже просто для себя разобраться и сделать что бы шагать дальше. На работу даже без заработной платы меня не возьмут, потому что никому не нужен сотрудник которого надо учить, очень сложно все делать самому когда за спиной нет не одного знакомого разработчика.

Comment: @D-side вроде бы верно, но все равно не срабатывает  <%= form_for :todo, url: todo_create_path, id: "form" do |f| %>
 
        <p>
            <%= f.text_field :text, placeholder:"Название задачи..."%>
        </p>
 
        <p>
            <%= f.collection_select(:project_id, Project.all, :id, :title) %>
        </p>
  
 <p>
  
  <%= link_to "Submit", todo_create_path, id: "your_link" %>
  </p>

<% end %>

Comment: Вы упорно игнорируете документацию к `form_for`... :)

Answer (score 0):

Вы передаете пустую форму. У вас 2 формы. В форме с id `form` полей нет. Вы ее передаете на сервер. Откройте получившийся html в отладчике и посмотрите, что передается серверу при нажатии на ваш **link**.

Использовать **link** для передачи данных - это очень плохая практика.

Добавьте `id` к первой форме и уберите его со второй. Получиться примерно вот так

```
<h1>Здачи</h1>

<table>


  <% @project_index.each do |project| %>
    <tr>
<h2><%= project.title %></h2>

    <ul>
    <% project.todos.each do |todo| %>
        <li><%= todo.text %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</table>

    <h2>Новая задача</h2>
  <%= form_for :todo, url: todo_create_path, html: { id: "form" } do |f| %>

        <p>
            <%= f.text_field :text, placeholder:"Название задачи..."%>
        </p>

        <p>
            <%= f.collection_select(:project_id, Project.all, :id, :title) %>
        </p>

<%= form_tag root_path do %>
<%= link_to "OK", todo_create_path, id: "your_link" %>
<% end %>
<% end %>


</div>
```

Comment: таково условие задачи, что должна быть не кнопка а именно линк, других вариантов я не нашел,почему я передаю пустую форму? форма  id form указано в aplication.js является кнопкой .submit она передает что выше :text и :project_id, ведь если добавить форму <%= f.submit %> это будет равносильно этой кнопке? или я не прав? я не утверждаю потому что я плохо еще знаком с данным языком, я пытался сделать так что бы вместо <%= f.submit %>  был линк равносильный ей, но не выходит.

Comment: да действительно ничего не передает, как сделать что бы передавались значения, я не понимать

Comment: вот так работает     <h2>Новая задача</h2>
  <%= form_for :todo, url: todo_create_path do |f| %>
 
        <p>
            <%= f.text_field :text, placeholder:"Название задачи..."%>
        </p>
 
        <p>
            <%= f.collection_select(:project_id, Project.all, :id, :title) %>
        </p>
  
   <%= f.submit %>

<% end %> , но мне необходимо сделать <%= f.submit %> ссылкой, у меня не получается, и не могу понять что я делаю не так

Comment: я дополнил ответ. попробуйте. еще раз повторю использовать ссылку - это не правильно.